# Using jQuery to load templates - wrong div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery to load three templates into the main page. The files are as follows:

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="content">   
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
<script> 
    $(function(){
         $(".header").load("/views/header.html");
         $(".content").load("/views/content.html");
         $(".footer").load("/views/footer.html"); 
    });
</script>
</body>
```

**header.html**

```
<div>Header</div>
```

**content.html**

```
<div>Content</div>
```

**footer.html**

```
<div>Footer</div>
```

For whatever reasons, the header.html is loaded into the content div (I am using Bracket as the editor). Am I doing something wrong? How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: There's no way to tell. Given the code you're showing, it should work, although the `script` tag should be within the `body` tag.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan updated my question

Comment: Are you sure that you did not copy/paste the same `html` at three separate files at text editor?

Comment: Are sure the file contents is what you show above? eg, isn't `<div>Header</div>` by accident in the content file?

Comment: @jao 100% sure... Also, both <div> Header </div> and <div> Content </div> is in content div... no idea why

Comment: Press `F12` in your browser and check your browser console for errors

Comment: It's possible you must have named the wrong files

Comment: Can you create a plnkr http://plnkr.co to reproduce issue? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @OkeTega All contents are loaded correctly - just in the wrong place

Comment: Kinda solved - seems to be a Bracket cosmetic thing.

Comment: Alright. Good to know

Comment: Cannot reproduce http://plnkr.co/edit/Cs0MhzQj535zUExAXI7a?p=preview